# Cannot find module (node.js / npm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I run the command "node run index.js" but I keep getting met with an error saying:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\giann\Desktop\Bot\run'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re telling `node` to execute a script called `run`, with `index.js` being an argument to `run`:

> ```
> Usage: node [options] [ -e script | script.js | - ] [arguments]
>        node inspect script.js [arguments]
> ```

You may be confusing `npm` (which does have a verb called `run`) and `node`.

`npm run` is for executing scripts defined in `package.json`. It’s not for running files.

tl;dr: You most likely want `node index.js`.